# What's the version of ADT for Android 4.2?

Tags: android

My question is : is the ADT related to a specific android version?
i mean when we say for exp android 4.2 is that mean that we are using ( the plugin) ADT 21.0.1??
or Android version and ADT version are not realated?

Answer (score 1):

> is the ADT related to a specific android version?

No.

> or Android version and ADT version are not realated?

Correct. There usually is an ADT release around the same time of an Android SDK release, but the ADT also is updated in between SDK releases.

Comment: But here in my eclipse the ADT and the SDK have the same version ( 21.0.1) even though not any relation?

Comment: The ADT and the SDK tools are the same version. The SDK tools has nothing to do with the Android OS version.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the Android [API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).